# Gitlab CI Not pulling latest submodule

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a project that has multiple submodules.

If I push a commit for the main project the CI scripts work perfectly, pulls the submodules no issues.

If however the commit to the main project contains an update to one of the submodules, I get the error

```
"could not read user name etc...."
```

To rectify I have to repush the main project

my CI scripts pulls submodule by

```
build_project:
  stage: build
  variables:
     GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  script:
  - "curl
```

Thanks